# localhost on a Mac, mySQL Root, write enabling folders, and migrating to a real server

Tags: macos, permissions, phpmyadmin, root, directory

I'm developing a site on an XAMPP localhost on a Mac. I manipulate my mySQL database via phpMyAdmin (not comfortable with the command line).

Everything works fine (I know, right!).

2 things have got me worried for when I eventually move my site to a real online live server.

First the background:

1) I am using a CMS/Framework type thing. When trying to install it (in the htdocs folder), I found that I needed to write-enable some folder or the other (FileSystem permissions in Finder). So I write-enabled all the folders contained in the mother folder. Mac's have 3 default types of users (right-click a folder in Finder and choose info). They are "Me", "admin" and "everyone". I right-clicked the mother folder (in Finder), selected "Read&Write" for all 3 types of users, and chose "Apply to enclosed items." And the installation worked out fine.

2) I am able to come and go as I please into phpMyAdmin to directly manipulate my database. I presume phpMyAdmin recognizes me as Root. I do not have a password for Root. I do have a separate user created with a password (let's call the user "specificdbuser") and I use "specificdbuser" to connect to the database from within my site's PHP code.

My concerns regarding 1 & 2 are:

1) I'm presuming that enabling Read&Write permissions for all 3 types of users, and in particular for all folders and items within the mother folder, is a security risk. Is there a better way? (a) How do I figure out which folders need to be writeable so that I only make those writeable instead of making everything writeable?, and (b) Instead of giving Read&Write permissions to the 3 default Mac user types, should I instead be creating some new type of user (Root? specificdbuser?) and only give that user permission to Read&Write permissions? As this is a website, do I need to give "everyone" permission to Read&Write? What the heck does "everyone" mean anyway?

2) Let's say I eventually set up my database's Root account with a password. When I eventually migrate my localhost site to a real live online server, will this Root / password combination work on that site too?

Answer (score 0):

1. I'm kind of confused, are you talking about FileSystem permissions or MySQL Database permission?  If it is a FileSystem question, then please check the web service user that runs your PHP scripts.  If it's a database permission, then please refer to #2 answer.
2. I would say, for security reason never use the "root" when connecting to your database.  I would suggest you setup the same user name/password/permissions on your local and in server.  But if that doesn't make sense you can have a config file that says if "localhost" then db_user = blah_blah, else if server side db_user = blah.

Comment: I'm talking about FileSystem permissions (Folder permissions in Finder). Thanks for the feedback. I've edited my post for clarity.

Comment: I don't use "root" when connecting to my database. I use the user "specificdbuser" when connecting to my database. I mentioned this in my post, but it's a long post so it's understandably easy to miss :-)

Comment: In #2, you mentioned "Root" account.  I'm assuming you are using Apache+PHP+MySQL, therefore whatever user/group that your Apache runs should have the permission to a folder/file that you want to access.  First check what user/group your Apache runs and grant the folder/file that you want to have your web script want's to access.